# Can't mass-assign, when i build a has one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Order.rb:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_one :review
end
```

Review.rb:

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order
end
```

I need to build a review, im using this method:

```
  class OrdersController < ApplicationController
    def build_review
      @review = Review.new(:order => @order)
    end
```

but i get this error:
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: order

any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to white list order for mass assignment via a params hash. Read http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html

Add this to the Review model

`attr_accessible :order`

Comment: rodrigo, if nullref was able to help you, consider marking it as an answer.

Comment: @RodrigoZurek, yep, accepting the answer will show your gratitude towards the person who helped you as well as if some one else will get the same issue, he/she will be able to easily find the working solution

Comment: yea i was going to, but stackoverflow made me wait 10 minutes to make it an answer, now is done ! thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use `@review = @order.build_review` instead of adding this to attr_accessible. Just in case ;)